# Pass argument to loop in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I'm stuck with what I think is relatively simple issue. I have a part of the code looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(ls -l /home/user_name/)
for f in ${file}; do
    awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
done
```

The idea is like this. On system there is user named `user_name`. Inside his home folder he has one type of files, let's say `xxx.txt`, `yyy.txt`. Inside those files there is data for which I want to take the second column (that's what awk is used for). How can I run this loop, so it would be checked for all files inside the directory? If I add something like this `awk 'NR==1{print $2}' $f` it,s checking only one file and for rest it's reporting with errors.

Comment: you are using `ls -l` (lowercase alphabet `l`, not number `1`)... and even then you should avoid trying to use [output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)... try `for f in /home/user_name/*.txt` and then `awk 'NR==1{print $2}' "$f"`

Comment: or even simpler, instead of for-loop, just a simple `awk 'FNR==1{print $2}' /home/user_name/*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

use the files entry directly to awk and use the FNR (File NR) instead of NR that count for all file (so NR==1 only for the first, non empty, file)

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $2}' /home/user_name/*.txt
```

Could failed if you have too much file to pass via command (need another approach like a find ... -exec) in this specific case